# If I use 'would', can 'steps' follow?

Tags: present-tense, would, conditionals

A dissertation talks bout the usefulness of the approach it takes: "[a] study of this kind would be all the more useful if it steps beyond the polemics of grammar." If I use 'would', can 'steps' follow? And then, if one uses 'stepped' instead, would it not mean that the researcher has not undertaken the task?

Comment: steps beyond the polemics is not great. To go beyond the polemics on grammar. grammar doesn't have polemics so polemics of grammar doesn't work. "A study of this kind would be all the more useful it it went beyond the polemics on or about grammar".  Yes, would + simple past means the person did  not do it.

Answer (score 1):

This 'would' is counter-factual.  'Stepped' is the proper verb form. ('Steps' would work with 'will').  'Stepped' would not indicate that the task wasn't performed -- only that it wasn't performed as 'usefully' as it might have been.

Answer (score 0):

I see no grammatical reason why you would not use steps after would in this fashion.  From a usage point of view, it is rather awkward. I personally prefer the expression "goes beyond" to "steps beyond".

Hope that helps.